# Bit confused with SQL and Tomcat

Tags: java, sql, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I have a huge confusion with SQL and Tomcat. You see Ive an assignment where Ive to create a WebApp (JSP) using a java class. I already did this, its a Matrix calculator that is working perfectly fine. Now I need to make a Database to store the users that log in, the type of Matrix operation they used (Sum, Substract etc), make new accounts for this users and also have a admin user. I really don't know where to start, how to connect the Database to Tomcat or is it to the Java class or the JSP? Where can I do this, use Netbeans? I read something about a driver to install but like I really don't know what it means to install it, like where and to what program.

I'm using Linux as this is what I was told to use, I'm sorry if this is too much to ask. But really my teacher just gave us an example of how to write the tables of the Database as well as the types of variables and how to edit the tables. But the rest for me is unknown. Main question is where do I start?

Comment: In NetBeans IDE,start creating a web application(project) which will include codes of JSP which will use Java-Database Connectivity(JDBC) to connect a database(MySQL,Oracle,etc...) That's it,very simple.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! But I ask you, currently I only use the IDE to edit my JSPs and Java classes, I run my WebApp from the browser directly. Does this affect anything?

Comment: Who's "Ive"? Why doesn't (s)he ask the question?

Comment: Boris I'm sorry. What do you mean? by Ive I mean "I have" ... I dont mean to ask for codes or anything, I'm just asking how to start...

Comment: @Silvestrini- You don't need anything except a Database software like Oracle,MySQL,etc. which have databases to store data.  A sample example for database access in JSP is http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm

Comment: @shekharsuman I did install MySQL Workbench at the beginning of my class. Is this the program you say?

Comment: @Silvestrini- Yes,MySQL workbench probably will help you establish JDBC connection to a JSP web application. That's it---simple. Just type the codes in IDE and create a database in MySQL for storing/fetching data from database.

Comment: @shekharsuman thank you for the info! And after I do this, how does the JSP or java class, I really don't know who deals with this, knows where and how to know there is a Database? Also where do I save my .sql file? In the WEB-INF folder? Right next to classes?

Comment: @Silvestrini- Go through the above link posted by me as a comment! http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score -1):

At first you need a database.
Maybe you want to start with MySQL: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQL/article.html
After you created a database you can connect to this database via java: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html